# Performance of Ettercap

Tags: network-monitoring

Can I install Ettercap on a server and place it at ISP have speed 10Gbps(fiber) and I only MITM attack, not Sniff.  Speed  network has been diminished or not?

Assuming servers that support 10Gbps fiber card, RAM <128G, and 2 CPU Intel Xeon Core i5 or i7.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely do this . and of course it would decrease the speed of your clients . but in case that you set it up on ISP where BGP redirection happens the effect would be Negligible. but it all depends on your network equipment . but generally man in the middle  attack would decrease the speed for clients (which is obvious because of extra redirection) but i repeat that it depend on equipment and even where you set the MITM (directly in ISP servers which is fast or somewhere else in the network which would decrease the speed alot more ) .